# Comma when using passive voice

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should I put commas in sentences like this?

> The price of software is defined(,) based on...
>
> The amount is calculated(,) based on...
>
> computers(,) developed by...
>
> approvals for advertising and marketing activities(,) related to...

If it's a complicated question, what should I read to understand the rules?

Comment: The presence of commas has nothing to do with the voice of the verb in the main clause, but with whether the modifier is restrictive.

Answer (score -1):

Having a passive voice has nothing to do here.
I believe you need to study how the adjective phrases are omitted and reduced.